# Minimap avoiding change window

Tags: buffers, window-splitting, minimap

Recently I started using `minimap-mode`, but it has been a bit buggy as sometimes when I split the window and open two different buffers, it won't let me go back to a buffer with *code* (and minimap).

So I when I do `C-x o`, it goes to the other buffer for a second, the minimap appears, but suddenly it disappears and emacs sends me back to the previous buffer.

It is strange, since it is not happening always, so I really don't know what can be causing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It's been happening to me ever since I installed Emacs + Spacemacs.

After a year, I decided to fiddle with `M-x customize group` `minimap`, and just found out that the 3rd option from top to bottom, *"Minimap Automatically Delete Window:* [Toggle]  **off**", did the trick.

Now it's possible to `C-x o` between visible buffers.

*Edit:* However, `C-x o` may allow switching to the `minimap` buffer as well. Still, a minor, tolerable quirk in comparison to the original problem.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly on Emacs 26.1 and I haven't seen a problem yet with switching into the `minimap` buffer.